# Web Sockets communication using nodejs for connection between a web app and a charging device

Tags: node.js, websocket

I want to create an application in which my web app will work as remote , a node based web socket server will work as CMS(central management system) and an electric vehicle charger which will be my device. I want help in how to send instruction to my device according to the commands i receive from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Node-http-server) on your server, it is easy to use and has a socket client implementation in almost languages that exist.